# Drawing points to canvas with cordinates, not working as expected. P5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a problem when trying to draw a point to the canvas based on set x and y coordinates.

The code I've written:

```
let cord1x;
let cord1y;

let cord2x;
let cord2y;
function setup(){
    createCanvas(600, 400);

    cord1x = floor(random(width, height));
    cord1y = floor(random(width, height));

    cord2x = floor(random(width, height));
    cord2y = floor(random(width, height));


    let d = dist(cord1x, cord1y, cord2x, cord2y);
    console.log(d);
}
function draw(){
    noFill();

    background(51);

    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(8);
    point(cord1x, cord1y);
    point(cord2x, cord2y);
}
```

My expected output or result is the that the point should be drawn at the point set by the X and Y coords..

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your issue is, I see 3 buttons and then some circles on the screen?

Comment: @LukeGarrigan I am very sorry that the link didn't work. I have copied the code into the question now. Hopefully, it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - OP completely changed the question, so now answer is redundant.

I'm struggling to understand what the issue is.

> My expected output or result is that the point should be drawn as set

From that I guess you mean you want the circles to be drawn in some sort of set? I deduced this because I noticed you are looping to the `width` and the `height` but aren't actually doing anything with that data, so you had:

> ```
>   for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 25) {
>     for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 25) {
>       noStroke();
>       fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
>       ellipse(random(0, 400), random(0, 400), 40, 40);
>
>     }
>   }
> ```

But you're just setting the ellipses in a random position anyhow, so `x <= width` and `y <= height` seem almost unnecessary.

What I think potentially you want is to display them in a non random position:

```js
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 25) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 25) {
      noStroke();
      fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));
      ellipse(x, y, 40, 40);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am very sorry for the inconvenience, you should be able to read my question better now.

Answer (score -1):

So apparently I'm pretty stupid.

```
cord1x = floor(random(width, height));
cord1y = floor(random(width, height));

cord2x = floor(random(width, height));
cord2y = floor(random(width, height));
```

Should be

```
cord1x = floor(random(width));
cord1y = floor(random(height));

cord2x = floor(random(width));
cord2y = floor(random(height));
```

Comment: I am very confused, you've edited the question but it's now completely different? May as well be a different question.

Comment: Yes I have. :).